# Return results to the caller with a throttling queue

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

Building on a [snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/5o/title/Throttling-agent) and answer, would it be possible to return results to the caller from the throttling queue? I've tried [PostAndAsyncReply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/mailboxprocessor.postandasyncreply%5B'msg%2C'reply%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) to receive reply on a channel but it's throwing an error if I pipe it with Enqueue. Here's the code.

Appreciate a F# core vanilla based solution around Queue or Mailbox design patterns.

**Question**

The question is to be able to call functions asynchronously based on the throttle (max 3 at a time), passing each item from the array, wait on the whole queue/array until it's finished while collecting all the results and then return the results to the caller. (Return the results to the caller is what's pending in here)

**Callee Code**

```
// Message type used by the agent - contains queueing
// of work items and notification of completion
type ThrottlingAgentMessage =
  | Completed
  | Enqueue of Async<unit>

/// Represents an agent that runs operations in concurrently. When the number
/// of concurrent operations exceeds 'limit', they are queued and processed later
let throttlingAgent limit =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    async {
      // The agent body is not executing in parallel,
      // so we can safely use mutable queue & counter
      let queue = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Async<unit>>()
      let running = ref 0

      while true do

        // Enqueue new work items or decrement the counter
        // of how many tasks are running in the background
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        match msg with
        | Completed -> decr running
        | Enqueue w -> queue.Enqueue(w)

        // If we have less than limit & there is some work to
        // do, then start the work in the background!
        while running.Value < limit && queue.Count > 0 do
          let work = queue.Dequeue()
          incr running
          do! // When the work completes, send 'Completed'
              // back to the agent to free a slot
              async {
                do! work
                inbox.Post(Completed)
              }
              |> Async.StartChild
              |> Async.Ignore
    })


let requestDetailAsync (url: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
     async {
       Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
       try
           do! Async.Sleep(1000) // let's say each request takes about a second
           return Ok (url + ":body...")
       with :? WebException as e ->
           return Error {Code = "500"; Message = "Internal Server Error"; Status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError}
     }

let requestMasterAsync() : Async<Result<System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<_>, Error>> =
    async {
        let urls = [|
                    "http://www.example.com/1";
                    "http://www.example.com/2";
                    "http://www.example.com/3";
                    "http://www.example.com/4";
                    "http://www.example.com/5";
                    "http://www.example.com/6";
                    "http://www.example.com/7";
                    "http://www.example.com/8";
                    "http://www.example.com/9";
                    "http://www.example.com/10";
                |]

        let results = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<_>()
        let agent = throttlingAgent 3

        for url in urls do
            async {
                let! res = requestDetailAsync url
                results.Add res
            }
            |> Enqueue
            |> agent.Post

        return Ok results
    }
```

**Caller Code**

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.TestRequestMasterAsync() =
    match Entity.requestMasterAsync() |> Async.RunSynchronously with
    | Ok result -> Console.WriteLine result
    | Error error -> Console.WriteLine error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Hopac.Streams` for that. With such tool it is pretty trivial:

```
open Hopac
open Hopac.Stream
open System

let requestDetailAsync url = async {
   Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
   try
       do! Async.Sleep(1000) // let's say each request takes about a second
       return Ok (url + ":body...")
   with :? Exception as e ->
       return Error e
 }

let requestMasterAsync() : Stream<Result<string,exn>> =
    [| "http://www.example.com/1"
       "http://www.example.com/2"
       "http://www.example.com/3"
       "http://www.example.com/4"
       "http://www.example.com/5"
       "http://www.example.com/6"
       "http://www.example.com/7"
       "http://www.example.com/8"
       "http://www.example.com/9"
       "http://www.example.com/10" |]
    |> Stream.ofSeq
    |> Stream.mapPipelinedJob 3 (requestDetailAsync >> Job.fromAsync)

requestMasterAsync()
|> Stream.iterFun (printfn "%A")
|> queue //prints all results asynchronously

let allResults : Result<string,exn> list = 
    requestMasterAsync()
    |> Stream.foldFun (fun results cur -> cur::results ) []
    |> run //fold stream into list synchronously
```

**ADDED**
In case you want to use only vanilla `FSharp.Core` with mailboxes only try this:

```
type ThrottlingAgentMessage =
  | Completed
  | Enqueue of Async<unit>

let inline (>>=) x f = async.Bind(x, f)
let inline (>>-) x f = async.Bind(x, f >> async.Return)

let throttlingAgent limit =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let queue = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Async<unit>>()

        let startWork work = 
            work
            >>- fun _ -> inbox.Post Completed
            |> Async.StartChild |> Async.Ignore

        let rec loop curWorkers =
            inbox.Receive()
            >>= function
            | Completed when queue.Count > 0 -> 
                queue.Dequeue() |> startWork
                >>= fun _ -> loop curWorkers
            | Completed -> 
                loop (curWorkers - 1)
            | Enqueue w when curWorkers < limit ->
                w |> startWork
                >>= fun _ -> loop (curWorkers + 1)
            | Enqueue w ->
                queue.Enqueue w
                loop curWorkers

        loop 0)
    Enqueue >> agent.Post
```

It is pretty much the same logic, but slightly optimized to not use queue if there is free worker capacity (just start job and don't bother with queue/dequeue).

`throttlingAgent` is a function `int -> Async<unit> -> unit`
Because we don't want client to bother with our internal `ThrottlingAgentMessage` type.

use like this:

```
let throttler = throttlingAgent 3

for url in urls do
    async {
        let! res = requestDetailAsync url
        results.Add res
    }
    |> throttler
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but not only I'd lose the chance for real knowledge how it can work within the mailbox and f# but incorporating a new library tool will open a new front of questions and problems. I'm sticking to find a pattern oriented solution within F#, unless you can tell me that mailbox is not an answer and it's a dead end then I'd look towards general async queue patterns.

Comment: @Developer11 your original question doesn't contain "FSharp.Core only" requirement :P

Comment: lol, ok, I'll add that, I assumed since I wrote core based vanilla code :)

Comment: Can you perhaps append an attempt to your answer. I can help with some more descriptions. Imagine a Mailbox that you pass an async fun along with a throttle value max and an array. Mailbox retrieves max slots of values from the array, and calls the async func concurrently while storing the results, and then it iterates on the next 3 until finish and then when it ends it returns the result to the caller.

Comment: @Developer11 added vanilla version

Comment: not seeing any output, I guess we have to add wait somewhere to be able to see the results. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5MCO.png

Comment: @Developer11 code in your screenshot working as it should because your concurrent bag is being filled asynchronously.

Comment: yes, i agree it's working but that's the point of having results at the caller level so we can iterate through it.

Comment: @Developer11 as workaround you could do infinite cycle until concurrent bag contains same amount us urls array. But I think you are doing something wrong

Comment: this tells me that the solution using Mailbox is entirely wrong, I should look somewhere else like building my own queue design pattern

Comment: Can you make mailbox return concurrent collection of results

Comment: I was able to get it right, my conclusion is this Mailbox with throttle snippet out there is a distraction, now I could have the solution with `PostAndReply` and return all results from there but in essence Mailbox is for sending messages to some target. I heard the train analogy, the train (message) is processed from station to station or envelope is passed from each successive location, and is not part of the paradigm to return the result to the source.